# draw a random number from an interval and measure its distance from the endpoints

Tags: r

can someone help me with the following problem? I tried to create a vector of data, then create a function that subtracts the value obtained from the vector to the endpoints, but it does not compile.

"Create a function that given an interval (a, b) as argument, generate within this interval a random number, and in a table or similar structure present:

> The number generated in the interval (a,b).
> The distance of the random value to the end "a" of the interval.
> The distance of the random value to the "b" end of the interval.
> A phrase or sentence indicating the "the r (random) value is closest to the end ....... " this according to whether "a" or "b" corresponds to "a" or "b".

Comment: Could you had what has failed? From which distribution are you sampling?

Comment: Homework questions are welcome [but following community standards](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) we ask that you show what you have tried and demonstrate your efforts.

Comment: When you say your function "does not compile", it could be a simple syntax error we can point out. Or it could be a larger misunderstanding that we can correct. But if you don't show anything that you tried, you're just asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: I had a wrong command in the function, but it came out, should I upload my answer here? :3